# Is there really no way to print a signed number without a sign in C?

Tags: c

I tried converting it to unsigned and declaring it as unsigned. It didn't work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number, modulo;
    int result = 0;

    printf("Please provide an integer: ");
    scanf("%i", &number);

    while (number != 0) {
        modulo = number % 10;   
        result += modulo;
        number = number / 10;
    }

    printf("%i", result);            
    printf("The sum of the digits of provided number is %i\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear, could you give an example of what is not working?

Comment: @5132089afsld, instead of adding a comment, please edit your question to include your code example.

Comment: Please do not destroy your posts, people have taken time answering them.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that `x` is an `int` variable, `printf("%d", x<0 ? -x : x)` prints `x` without a sign for all values except `INT_MIN` on a 2's complement platform.

R.. below has suggested:

```
printf("%u", (unsigned) (x<0 ? (-1 - x) + 1 : x);
```

… because that handles `INT_MIN` too for any reasonable platform.

Comment: Using `(unsigned)(-1-x) + 1` and switching the format to `%u` will avoid the `INT_MIN` issue assuming the absolute value of `INT_MIN` is representable in `unsigned`.

Comment: @R.. `(unsigned)-x` works just as well on a 2's compliment platform without restricting yourself with the explicit 2's compliment

Comment: @SteveCox: No it doesn't. `-x` invokes UB if `x==INT_MIN`. My code makes no assumption about 2's complement. The expression `-1-(x)` is just one that's guaranteed not to overflow.

Comment: Well it happens to be equal to `~x` for twos complement, but that's not the purpose here. Rather one could say that's the reason that twos complement is the only sane signed representation. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
#define ABS(x) (((x)<0)?(-(x)):(x))
```

(Or as correctly pointed out, there's the built-in `abs()` in `stdlib`).

Comment: It's **much** more better to use `abs()` from `stdlib.h`: [man abs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abs). The macro has a ton of subtle pitfalls.

Comment: @SamProtsenko `abs` function has the same pitfalls: UB with `INT_MIN`.

Comment: Yeah, there's the -MAX_INT problem, and there's always the the problem of putting an argument with side effects into a macro. I'm an old fart...I'd forgotten that stdlib added that a while back.

Comment: `#define SAFE_ABS(x) ((x)<0 ? (unsigned)(-1-(x))+1 : (x))`